# JProfiler: Help wanted for memory profiling - where do I find line numbers for where objects are being allocated

Tags: jprofiler

newby alert:

I have started my 10 day trial and I am having issues figuring out how to get it to find what I'm looking for.  I have a fairly complex single threaded Java app that I'm trying to get to never GC.  I pool all my objects.  However I must have missed a few things.  I'd like to find out where I'm releasing the last reference of the objects that are going back to the heap.  If I cant find that, it would suffice to at least know where the memory is being created that is later being GC'd.

This is what I'm doing so far:
1.  click on Live memory / Recorded Objects
2.  Click record and select "Garbage collected objects, All allocations"
3.  Click on "Run GC"

so now a bunch of stuff appears.  I was hoping I could simply double click and it would give me line numbers and fun stuff like that.  Similar to what I got when I would run HPROF.

4. I right click on one of the items and select "show allocation tree for selection"

Still no line numbers... it does give me the method name though.  If the method is large it's kinda complicated to figure out where the memory is being created.

Also when I stop recording, is there a way to clear everything  in the recorded objects view so I can start over with a new recording?

Answer (score 0):

In the profiling settings you can switch on line number resolution.

[image]

> Also when I stop recording, is there a way to clear everything in the recorded objects view so I can start over with a new recording?

When you start recording again, all previous data is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Click "Live memory - Recorded Objects"
2. Choose the Objects you want to watch then right click "Show Selection In Heaper Walker" and choose "Show in current heap dump"
3. Choose the Objects you want to watch in the new Heap Walker window and right click and choose "Use Selected Objects" and choose "Allocations". Then you can see the allocation tree of the Objects, by read the method code you can locate the line number you want.